# how to include/get "target contact" in xero "invoices" post/get api calls.

Tags: xero-api

I am new to xero and currently doing POC, by using these services ->[GET call](https://app.xero.com/Preview/invoices/get)
Can I get/add target contact to invoice using given service as images which are uploded. I referred [API docmentaion](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/invoices). But no luck. Can you please help me out.

[image: Add customer by UI]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to find what you're after via the Linked Transactions (billable expenses) endpoint.

https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/linked-transactions